# What is this notation from a paper/book by Hestenes on geometrics?

Tags: notation

I'm reading a paper
Vectors, Spinors, and Complex Numbers in Classical
and Quantum Physics
David Hestenes

and it presented this equation, with notation I've never seen before.  It's like doing the dot and wedge product of subscripts?

I could use a reference on where to learn about this notation and how to do it and follow it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd46j.png

Any help?

Comment: It looks like you just have a rendering problem in whatever PDF viewing software you used to create that image. I typed the name of the paper in to the search engine and found the paper, and there are bold lower case sigmas ($\mathbf\sigma$) in there in my browser. As to what the notation means, it looks like the paper spends some time explaining what it is.

Comment: Oh jeez, I should have guessed it was a pdf problem instead of some odd notation.  Thank you!

Comment: Well we solved one problem today anyway. Good luck with figuring out the notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add an image into a comment, please consider this answer a comment to your question. Here is a screengrab from my browser (google chrome) of http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf-preAdobe8/VeSp&ComUpdated.pdf.

[image]